# "AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'descendants' error with automation scraping with bs4 and selenium

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

My objective with this code is to scrap the allocation of brazilian funds.

```
PATH = (r"C:\Users\gustavo.vieira\Desktop\python\drivers\msedgedriver.exe")
funds_list = ['VINLAND MACRO MASTER FUNDO DE INVESTIMENTO MULTIMERCADO']
url = 'https://cvmweb.cvm.gov.br/SWB/Sistemas/SCW/CPublica/CConsolFdo/FormBuscaParticFdo.aspx'


for i in funds_lista:
    driver = webdriver.Edge(PATH)
    driver.get(url)
    search = driver.find_element_by_name("txtCNPJNome")
    search.send_keys(i)
    search.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
    driver.find_element_by_link_text(i).click()
    font = driver.find_element_by_link_text('Composição da Carteira').click()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(font)
    rows = soup.find_all("tr")
    print(rows)
```

My problem starts with bs4, I already tried to scrap the table using `soup.find_all('table', id ='dlAplics')`, or using (class_, all of them return an error. I already saw a lot of videos but I'm feeling unable to solve that by myself right now.

Comment: _all of them return a error_: What do you see?

Comment: I received a lot of different erros trying solve it, but the mainly was "AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'descendants'"

Comment: What are you trying to scrape?

Comment: Second table of that page, where appear "Ativo" "Classificação" until the final of that first table, there are all informations from last month of allocation from brazilian investiment funds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### What happens?

You assign the `.click()` to variable `font` and try to process it with `BeautifulSoup` what won't work.

#### How to fix?

Instead provide `driver.page_source` to `BeautifulSoup` to operate on the html.

Change:

```
font = driver.find_element_by_link_text('Composição da Carteira').click()
soup = BeautifulSoup(font)
```

to:

```
driver.find_element_by_link_text('Composição da Carteira').click()
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source)
```

**Note** * Id's in general are unique so you could use `soup.find('table', id ='dlAplics')` instead of `find_all()` to directly operate on this table.*

---

#### Output

```html
<table border="1" cellpadding="4" cellspacing="0" class="BodyPP" id="dlAplics" rules="all" style="border-width:1px;border-style:solid;width:100%;border-collapse:collapse;">
<tbody><tr style="background-color:#ACC2D8;">
<td align="center" colspan="11"><b>Lista de Aplicações<br/>Clique sobre o ativo para mais informações.</b></td>
</tr><tr style="background-color:#ACC2D8;">
<td align="center" rowspan="3" style="width:30%;"><b>Ativo</b></td><td align="center" rowspan="3"><b>Classificação</b></td><td align="center" rowspan="3"><b>Empresa Ligada</b></td><td align="center" colspan="4"><b>Negócios Realizados no Mês</b></td><td align="center" colspan="4"><b>Posição Final</b></td>
</tr><tr style="background-color:#ACC2D8;">
<td align="center" colspan="2"><b>Vendas</b></td><td align="center" colspan="2"><b>Aquisições</b></td><td align="center" rowspan="2" style="width:7%;"><b>Quant.</b></td><td align="center" colspan="2"><b>Valores</b></td><td align="center" rowspan="2" style="width:7%;"><b>% Patr. Líq.</b></td>
</tr><tr style="background-color:#ACC2D8;">
<td align="center" style="width:7%;"><b>Quant.</b></td><td align="center" style="width:7%;"><b>Valor<br/></b></td><td align="center" style="width:7%;"><b>Quant.</b></td><td align="center" style="width:7%;"><b>Valor<br/></b></td><td align="center" style="width:7%;"><b>Custo<br/></b></td><td align="center" style="width:7%;"><b>Mercado<br/></b></td>
</tr><tr style="background-color:Cornsilk;">
<td align="left"><span onclick="AbrirDet('CDADetAplic.aspx?PkCDAAplic=72375627')" style="cursor: hand; COLOR: olivedrab"><b></b> Ações<br/><b>Cod. Ativo:</b> RDOR3<br/><b>Dt. Ini. Vigen.:</b> 10/12/2020<br/></span></td><td align="center"><span id="dlAplics__ctl1_lbNConfTpNegoc">Para<br/>negociação</span></td><td align="center"><span id="dlAplics__ctl1_lbNConfEmpLigada">Não</span></td><td align="center">38.219</td><td align="center"><span id="dlAplics__ctl1_lbNConfVlVendasNegoc">2.139.131,81</span></td><td align="center">37.866</td><td align="center"><span id="dlAplics__ctl1_lbNConfVlAquisNegoc">2.239.218,96</span></td><td align="center">1.502</td><td align="center"><span id="dlAplics__ctl1_lbNConfVlCustoCorrecPosFim"></span></td><td align="center"><span id="dlAplics__ctl1_lbNConfVlPosFim">75.355,34</span></td><td align="center">0,005</td>
</tr><tr style="background-color:#FAEFCA;">
<td align="left"><span onclick="AbrirDet('CDADetAplic.aspx?PkCDAAplic=72375615')" style="cursor: hand; COLOR: olivedrab"><b></b> Ações<br/><b>Cod. Ativo:</b> RDOR3<br/><b>Dt. Ini. Vigen.:</b> 25/06/2021<br/></span></td><td align="center"><span id="dlAplics__ctl2_lbNConfAltTpNegoc">Para<br/>negociação</span></td><td align="center"><span id="dlAplics__ctl2_lbNConfAltEmpLigada">Não</span></td><td align="center">38.219</td><td align="center"><span id="dlAplics__ctl2_lbNConfAltVlVendasNegoc">2.139.131,81</span></td><td align="center">37.866</td><td align="center"><span id="dlAplics__ctl2_lbNConfAltVlAquisNegoc">2.239.218,96</span></td><td align="center">1.502</td><td align="center"><span id="dlAplics__ctl2_lbNConfAltVlCustoCorrecPosFim"></span></td><td align="center"><span id="dlAplics__ctl2_lbNConfAltVlPosFim">75.355,34</span></td><td align="center">0,005</td>
</tr><tr style="background-color:Cornsilk;">
<td align="left"><span onclick="AbrirDet('CDADetAplic.aspx?PkCDAAplic=72375728')" style="cursor: hand; COLOR: olivedrab"><b></b> Certificado ou recibo de depósito de valores mobiliários<br/><b>Descrição:</b> TAEE11 - TRANS. ALIANCA DE ENERGIA ELETRICA S/A - TAEE11<br/><b>CNPJ do emissor:</b> 07.859.971/0001-30<br/><b>Denominação Social do emissor: </b> TRANS. ALIANCA DE ENERGIA ELETRICA S/A<br/></span></td><td align="center"><span id="dlAplics__ctl3_lbNConfTpNegoc">Para<br/>negociação</span></td><td align="center"><span id="dlAplics__ctl3_lbNConfEmpLigada">Não</span></td><td align="center">0</td><td align="center"><span id="dlAplics__ctl3_lbNConfVlVendasNegoc">0,00</span></td><td align="center">0</td><td align="center"><span id="dlAplics__ctl3_lbNConfVlAquisNegoc">0,00</span></td><td align="center">979</td><td align="center"><span id="dlAplics__ctl3_lbNConfVlCustoCorrecPosFim"></span></td><td align="center"><span id="dlAplics__ctl3_lbNConfVlPosFim">35.273,37</span></td><td align="center">0,002</td>
</tr><tr style="background-color:#FAEFCA;">
<td align="left"><span onclick="AbrirDet('CDADetAplic.aspx?PkCDAAplic=72375488')" style="cursor: hand; COLOR: olivedrab"><b></b> Cotas de Fundos<br/><b></b> HASHDEX NASDAQ ETHEREUM REFERENCE PRICE FUNDO DE ÍNDICE<br/></span></td><td align="center"><span id="dlAplics__ctl4_lbNConfAltTpNegoc"></span></td><td align="center"><span id="dlAplics__ctl4_lbNConfAltEmpLigada">Não</span></td><td align="center">23.967</td><td align="center"><span id="dlAplics__ctl4_lbNConfAltVlVendasNegoc">1.667.612,78</span></td><td align="center">209.290</td><td align="center"><span id="dlAplics__ctl4_lbNConfAltVlAquisNegoc">15.823.222,00</span></td><td align="center">142.956</td><td align="center"><span id="dlAplics__ctl4_lbNConfAltVlCustoCorrecPosFim"></span></td><td align="center"><span id="dlAplics__ctl4_lbNConfAltVlPosFim">11.436.480,00</span></td><td align="center">0,787</td>
</tr><tr style="background-color:Cornsilk;">
<td align="left"><span onclick="AbrirDet('CDADetAplic.aspx?PkCDAAplic=72375486')" style="cursor: hand; COLOR: olivedrab"><b></b> Cotas de Fundos<br/><b></b> HASHDEX NASDAQ CRYPTO INDEX FUNDO DE INDICE<br/></span></td><td align="center"><span id="dlAplics__ctl5_lbNConfTpNegoc"></span></td><td align="center"><span id="dlAplics__ctl5_lbNConfEmpLigada">Não</span></td><td align="center">628.668</td><td align="center"><span id="dlAplics__ctl5_lbNConfVlVendasNegoc">38.177.765,73</span></td><td align="center">634.819</td><td align="center"><span id="dlAplics__ctl5_lbNConfVlAquisNegoc">39.878.659,26</span></td><td align="center">87.530</td><td align="center"><span id="dlAplics__ctl5_lbNConfVlCustoCorrecPosFim"></span></td><td align="center"><span id="dlAplics__ctl5_lbNConfVlPosFim">5.487.255,70</span></td><td align="center">0,378</td>
</tr><tr style="background-color:#FAEFCA;">
<td align="left"><span onclick="AbrirDet('CDADetAplic.aspx?PkCDAAplic=72375484')" style="cursor: hand; COLOR: olivedrab"><b></b> Cotas de Fundos<br/><b></b> ISHARES S&amp;P 500 FUNDO DE INVESTIMENTO EM COTAS DE FUNDO DE ÍNDICE - INVESTIMENTO NO EXTERIOR<br/></span></td><td align="center"><span id="dlAplics__ctl6_lbNConfAltTpNegoc"></span></td><td align="center"><span id="dlAplics__ctl6_lbNConfAltEmpLigada">Não</span></td><td align="center">26.057</td><td align="center"><span id="dlAplics__ctl6_lbNConfAltVlVendasNegoc">7.285.144,24</span></td><td align="center">31.466</td><td align="center"><span id="dlAplics__ctl6_lbNConfAltVlAquisNegoc">8.871.406,46</span></td><td align="center">5.983</td><td align="center"><span id="dlAplics__ctl6_lbNConfAltVlCustoCorrecPosFim"></span></td><td align="center"><span id="dlAplics__ctl6_lbNConfAltVlPosFim">1.678.530,65</span></td><td align="center">0,116</td>
</tr><tr style="background-color:Cornsilk;">
<td align="left"><span onclick="AbrirDet('CDADetAplic.aspx?PkCDAAplic=72375640')" style="cursor: hand; COLOR: olivedrab"><b></b> Investimento no Exterior<br/><b>Nome do emissor: </b> CITCO - 376420,897566<br/><b>Venc.:</b> 31/12/2050<br/></span></td><td align="center"><span id="dlAplics__ctl7_lbNConfTpNegoc">Para<br/>negociação</span></td><td align="center"><span id="dlAplics__ctl7_lbNConfEmpLigada">Não</span></td><td align="center">0</td><td align="center"><span id="dlAplics__ctl7_lbNConfVlVendasNegoc">0,00</span></td><td align="center">0</td><td align="center"><span id="dlAplics__ctl7_lbNConfVlAquisNegoc">0,00</span></td><td align="center">376.421</td><td align="center"><span id="dlAplics__ctl7_lbNConfVlCustoCorrecPosFim"></span></td><td align="center"><span id="dlAplics__ctl7_lbNConfVlPosFim">257.652.646,82</span></td><td align="center">17,731</td>
</tr><tr style="background-color:#FAEFCA;">
<td align="left"><span onclick="AbrirDet('CDADetAplic.aspx?PkCDAAplic=72375755')" style="cursor: hand; COLOR: olivedrab"><b></b> Valores a pagar<br/><b>Descrição:</b> AURA33<br/><b>CNPJ do emissor:</b> 07.857.093/0001-14<br/><b>Denominação Social do emissor: </b> AURA MINERALS INC.<br/></span></td><td align="center"><span id="dlAplics__ctl8_lbNConfAltTpNegoc">Para<br/>negociação</span></td><td align="center"><span id="dlAplics__ctl8_lbNConfAltEmpLigada"></span></td><td align="center"></td><td align="center"><span id="dlAplics__ctl8_lbNConfAltVlVendasNegoc"></span></td><td align="center"></td><td align="center"><span id="dlAplics__ctl8_lbNConfAltVlAquisNegoc"></span></td><td align="center"></td><td align="center"><span id="dlAplics__ctl8_lbNConfAltVlCustoCorrecPosFim"></span></td><td align="center"><span id="dlAplics__ctl8_lbNConfAltVlPosFim">458.916,75</span></td><td align="center">-0,032</td>
</tr>
</tbody></table>
```

Comment: Doing that i receive back all html code where my id are, right? But i yet dont know how transform that to my data. All scraps that i did before was a page with only the table, i'm a little confused with this path to scrap.

Answer (score 1):

To scrape all the text from the first table on [Consulta a Carteiras de Fundos](https://cvmweb.cvm.gov.br/SWB/Sistemas/SCW/CPublica/CDA/CPublicaCDA.aspx?PK_PARTIC=163581&SemFrame=) page you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the [*visibility_of_element_located()*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50468629/python-selenium-wait-until-element-is-fully-loaded/50474905#50474905) and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Code block:

  ```
  driver.get("https://cvmweb.cvm.gov.br/SWB/Sistemas/SCW/CPublica/CConsolFdo/FormBuscaParticFdo.aspx")
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input#txtCNPJNome"))).send_keys("VINLAND MACRO MASTER FUNDO DE INVESTIMENTO MULTIMERCADO" + Keys.RETURN)
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a#ddlFundos__ctl0_lnkbtn1"))).click()
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT, "Composição da Carteira"))).click()
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//table[@id='tabAtivos']//table[@id='dlAplics']"))).text)
  ```
- Console output:

  ```
  Lista de Aplicações
  Clique sobre o ativo para mais informações.
  Ativo Classificação Empresa Ligada Negócios Realizados no Mês Posição Final
  Vendas Aquisições Quant. Valores % Patr. Líq.
  Quant. Valor
  Quant. Valor
  Custo
  Mercado
  Ações
  Cod. Ativo: RDOR3
  Dt. Ini. Vigen.: 10/12/2020
  Para
  negociação Não 38.219 2.139.131,81 37.866 2.239.218,96 1.502 75.355,34 0,005
  Ações
  Cod. Ativo: RDOR3
  Dt. Ini. Vigen.: 25/06/2021
  Para
  negociação Não 38.219 2.139.131,81 37.866 2.239.218,96 1.502 75.355,34 0,005
  Certificado ou recibo de depósito de valores mobiliários
  Descrição: TAEE11 - TRANS. ALIANCA DE ENERGIA ELETRICA S/A - TAEE11
  CNPJ do emissor: 07.859.971/0001-30
  Denominação Social do emissor: TRANS. ALIANCA DE ENERGIA ELETRICA S/A
  Para
  negociação Não 0 0,00 0 0,00 979 35.273,37 0,002
  Cotas de Fundos
  HASHDEX NASDAQ ETHEREUM REFERENCE PRICE FUNDO DE ÍNDICE
  Não 23.967 1.667.612,78 209.290 15.823.222,00 142.956 11.436.480,00 0,787
  Cotas de Fundos
  HASHDEX NASDAQ CRYPTO INDEX FUNDO DE INDICE
  Não 628.668 38.177.765,73 634.819 39.878.659,26 87.530 5.487.255,70 0,378
  Cotas de Fundos
  ISHARES S&P 500 FUNDO DE INVESTIMENTO EM COTAS DE FUNDO DE ÍNDICE - INVESTIMENTO NO EXTERIOR
  Não 26.057 7.285.144,24 31.466 8.871.406,46 5.983 1.678.530,65 0,116
  Investimento no Exterior
  Nome do emissor: CITCO - 376420,897566
  Venc.: 31/12/2050
  Para
  negociação Não 0 0,00 0 0,00 376.421 257.652.646,82 17,731
  Valores a pagar
  Descrição: AURA33
  CNPJ do emissor: 07.857.093/0001-14
  Denominação Social do emissor: AURA MINERALS INC.
  Para
  negociação 458.916,75 -0,032
  ```

Comment: Oh, i see. Thank you